# IE 10 on WP 8 is stuck in compatibility mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10, ie-compatibility-mode

I've got a Nokia Lumia 920, running Windows Phone 8 and IE 10. On my site, I had, at one point in time, the following code:

```
<iframe src="blank.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This was causing validation issues, and was forcing IE 10 on the phone to go into IE 7 compatibility mode. To fix this, I add some conditional comments to only load this version is IE 7 & 8 (where the `frameborder` attribute is needed), and load an `<iframe seamless>` in the other browsers.

I fixed this on my staging server, reloaded, and the user agent string updated to IE 10 mode. However, I pushed the code live, the same HTML is being served (from the same server setup) and on reloading the phone, the user agent still reports IE 7 compatibility mode.

**How can I force IE 10 out of compatibility view on this other server?**

A few notes:

- Clearing cache didn't help
- Nor did restarting
- I know about the `IE=Edge` meta, but a valid page is important in my case, so I don't want to use it
- Page code is extremely simple: HTML5 doctype, utf-8 `<meta>`, `<title>`, a few `<script>` tags, a `<style>` tag, and an `<iframe>`
- Both page and `<iframe>` contents validate as HTML5

Comment: In what way is using a meta element causing an invalid page?

Comment: @MrLister That `<meta>` property is not valid and causes validation errors. Try it on the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on an Intranet site, [IE will, by default, fallback to compatibility mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx). The only way to fix this is to use something like the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` tag or to serve that header via the server. To maintain a valid HTML5 site, using the server to send the content header is the preferred way to do it.

Comment: In addition, be sure to keep <meta> tags on the first part of the <head> tag, otherwise they might not be effective. I've just had an issue related to this, so I can confirm that for instance putting a <script> tag before the <meta>s seems to block them (and the site shows in compatibility mode...)